# Network error getting only on ANDROID M - All permissions fine. Using android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

Tags: android, react-native, axios, android-manifest, cleartext

I am getting network error with Axios on all the APIs `https:// too` react-native 0.65. My app was working fine on all the devices before I updated it to 0.65. The previous version was 0.61.

Now only on Android M (6) I am getting a Network error.

My `AndroidManifest`

```xml
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  
   <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"
        tools:node="remove" />
  
    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false"
      android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
      android:launchMode="singleTask"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

My `android/build.Gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
```

My `debug AndroidManifest`

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
      tools:targetApi="28"
      tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
      >

       <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>
```

```
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.65.1",
```

Answer (score 0):

It was due to some ssl certificate. Fixed